# Set ARCore Sceneview on another screen element

Tags: java, android, xml, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to display one arFragment twice on my screen by simply using the feed of one fragment and setting another screen element to the same, but I can't figure out which element to take.

I know, I get the current Camera image by calling

```
ArFragment arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                           .findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
Image image = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().acquireCameraImage();
```

But I don't know how to take another screen object and set the view to the feed, the arFragment gives me. Like, for example:

```
TextureView secondView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
secondView.setSurfaceTexture((SurfaceTexture) image);
```

yields an inconvertible types error.

I cannot use another arFragment, because that would have another camera already assigned (one that yields a black screen and a "camera already in use" error, obviously). I haven't found an

```
arFrame.assignCamera();
```

Method, which doesn't matter, since the camera used by the Fragment is only an object, not the real thing. But I can't figure out where the hardware is getting tied to the Fragment. And I can't read nor write there if I recall correctly.

I could convert the feed to a bitmap and maybe place it onto an imageView but I'm a little afraid to do this 60 times a second. There has to be a simple solution, right?...

Can't be so hard to display a view twice -.-

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it. It's a little magic with converting to bmp but guess there's really no direct way.

So I did initialize a bytebuffer, analyze the YUV components of the android.media.image, convert them to a Jpeg, then change it into a Bitmap, rotate it by 90° to match the original picture.

```
// get the arFragment
arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
ArSceneView arSceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();

// set up a Listener to trigger on every frame
arSceneView.getScene().addOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> 
{
  try 
  {
   frame = arSceneView.getArFrame();
   androidMediaImage = frame.acquireCameraImage();
   int imageWidth = androidMediaImage.getWidth();
   int imageHeight = androidMediaImage.getHeight();

   // select the target Container to display the image in
   ImageView secondView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
   byte[] nv21;

   // an Android.Media.Image is a YUV-Image which is made out of 3 planes
   ByteBuffer yBuffer = androidMediaImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
   ByteBuffer uBuffer = androidMediaImage.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
   ByteBuffer vBuffer = androidMediaImage.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

   // set up a Bytearray with the size of all the planes
   int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
   int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
   int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();

   nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];

   // Fill in the array. This code is directly taken from https://www.programcreek.com 
   //where it was pointed out that U and V have to be swapped
   yBuffer.get(nv21, 0 , ySize);
   vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
   vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

   // combine the three layers to one nv21 image
   YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, imageWidth, imageHeight, null);
   // Open a Bytestream to feed the compressor
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   // compress the yuv image to Jpeg. This is important, because the BitmapFactory can't read a 
   // yuv-coded image directly (belief me I tried -.-)
   yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 50, out);
   // now write down the bytes of the image into an array
   byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
   // and build the bitmap using the Factory
   Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);

   // use a Matrix for the rotation
   Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
   // the thing is basically a bunch of numbers which then can be used to compute the new location of each pixel
   rotationMatrix.postRotate(90);
   // the rotatedImage will be our target image
   Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage, 0,0, bitmapImage.getWidth(), bitmapImage.getHeight(), rotationMatrix, true);

   // it's so easy!!!!
   secondView.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);
  } catch (NotYetAviableException e) 
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
});
```

You can obviously correct me if I got it all wrong and there's a way simpler solution to that. But it works at least, so I'm happy <3